# How To Config ZPANEL Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2

I have found a beta version of Zpanel for Ubuntu 14.04 and I have installed it in my VPS.

My VPS: Ubuntu 14.04, 8GB RAM | 4 VCPU | 20.0GB Disk

After I installed I rebooted, and now I have one problem with this config!

```
root@green-code:~# service apache2 status
apache2 is not running

root@green-code:~# service apache2 start
Starting web server apache2 
The apache2 configtest failed.
```

Output of configtest was:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 222 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open 
configuration file /etc/zpanel/configs/apache/httpd.conf: No such file or 
directory

Action 'configtest' failed.

The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Any one can help me how to fix those configs?

I'm new with this, I want to learn more about servers, resellers, and sorry I can't speak good English and I can't explain perfectly!

Comment: What's the content of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, particularly line 222?

Comment: sorry but i don't have it now this problem has ben 6 months ago :/ now i have install sentora and is working without problems

Answer (score 0):

These sort of configuration issues are normally caused by a missing php-module that is being used within the config files i would highly recommend not using zpanel it is slow and clunky. I would say a better practice system is ispconfig-3. And easy to read configuration files that get generated.

No many people will be able to help without first seeing the configuration files.

Comment: thank you for this i will try this 
i don't know wich program is beter for what i want because this is my first time in this project (to open a hosting with vps) 
for this i find zpanel in google. 
and one last qestion 
maybe you can suggest any tutorial how to set a domain name in my vps and how to setup name servers for ubuntu 14.04 64bit !?
i have try with no ip work good but i want to add my domain name not one domain from no ip!

Comment: Ok nameservers for a website are nothing more than a records in your dns setup for exampl a record ip 1.1.1.1 name bob this would allow you to setup a name server of bob.domain.com  as bob.domain.com would point back to 1.1.1.1 <- the ip of your server. This can all be configured through ispconfig-3.